# Refresh Tkinter table

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm working on a Rush-Hour game. I'm building a gui to show solutions i'v found.
I built a table that holds the current state. Now i want to update the board to next state. How can i refresh the GUI?

```
import Tkinter as tk
dict = {'X':'red', 'A': 'cyan', 'B': 'dark green', 'C': 'gold', 'D': 'green2', 'E': 'tan1', 'F': 'deep pink', 'G': 'bisque2', 'H': 'navy', 'I': 'orange', 'J': 'khaki1', 'K': 'purple1', 'O': 'Lightblue3', 'P': 'salmon', 'Q': 'lemon chiffon', 'R': 'OliveDrab2'};
class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, board):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        t = SimpleTable(self, board, 8, 8)
        t.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        t.set(7,7,"2")

class SimpleTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, board, rows=8, columns=8):
        # use black background so it "peeks through" to 
        # form grid lines
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black")
        self._widgets = []
        for i in range(rows):
            current_row = []
            for j in range(columns):     
                if (i >= 1 and i <=6 and j >= 1 and j <=6):
                    vehicleId = board[i-1][j-1]
                    if (vehicleId != ' '):              
                        label = tk.Label(self, text=vehicleId, bg=dict[vehicleId], borderwidth=0, width=10)
                    else:
                        label = tk.Label(self, text=vehicleId, bg='gray75', borderwidth=0, width=10)                       
                elif (i == 3 and j == 7):
                    label = tk.Label(self, text="exit", bg='gray30', borderwidth=0, width=10)
                else:
                    label = tk.Label(self, text="", bg='gray60', 
                                 borderwidth=0, width=10)
                label.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky="nsew", padx=2, pady=2)
                current_row.append(label)
            self._widgets.append(current_row)
        for j in range(columns):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(j, weight=1)

    def set(self, row, column, value):
        widget = self._widgets[row][column]
        widget.configure(text=value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initial state
    board = [['O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],     ['O', 'X', 'X',' ', ' ', ' '], ['P', ' ', 'A', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q'], ['P', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', 'B'],['P', ' ', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B']]
    # second state
    board2 = [['O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], ['O', ' ', 'X','X', ' ', ' '], ['P', ' ', 'A', 'Q', 'Q', 'Q'], ['P', ' ', 'A', ' ', ' ', 'B'],['P', ' ', 'R', 'R', 'R', 'B']]
    app = ExampleApp(board)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep a reference to the widgets, which you can use later to change the text. For example, you could keep a list of labels for each row:

```
labels = []
for i in range(rows):
    labels.append([])
    for j in range(columns):
        ...
        label = Label(...)
        labels[-1].append(label)
...
```

To modify the text, use the `config` method of the label:

```
 for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        labels[i][j].config(text="this is new text")
```

Comment: in this case for every line i will replace the UI will refresh?

Comment: @itzikos: I don't understand your comment. The simplest thing will be to have two separate functions: one to create all the labels (with _no_ data), and a second function that can update the labels with the correct data.